# cmake -H to generate build files for CMake project?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I recently observed that the [CMake Tools Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools) in VS Code runs this command to generate the build file for a project I'm working on:

`/usr/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -H/home/tirthankar/projects/physicc/Light/Editor -B/home/tirthankar/projects/physicc/Light/build -G Ninja`

The part I am confused about is the `-H/home/tirthankar/projects/physicc/Light/Editor` part. I searched the [CMake Docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.21/) for this behavior, but all I could find for the `-H` was [this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#view-help):

[CMake Docs saying that `-H` is for printing the help docs to the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdZrR.png)

So the question is, what does `-H` do in CMake? Is it a standard feature? Is it a deprecated feature? Did the CMake Tools Extension make a mistake?

For reference, here is the entire output:

```
[kit] Successfully loaded 3 kits from /home/tirthankar/.local/share/CMakeTools/cmake-tools-kits.json
[main] Configuring folder: Light 
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -H/home/tirthankar/projects/physicc/Light/Editor -B/home/tirthankar/projects/physicc/Light/build -G Ninja
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.3.0
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.3.0
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] -- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so   
[cmake] -- Looking for pthread.h
[cmake] -- Looking for pthread.h - found
[cmake] -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
[cmake] -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
[cmake] -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
[cmake] -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
[cmake] -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
[cmake] -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
[cmake] -- Found Threads: TRUE  
[cmake] -- Using X11 for window creation
[cmake] -- Found X11: /usr/include   
[cmake] -- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
[cmake] -- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
[cmake] -- Looking for gethostbyname
[cmake] -- Looking for gethostbyname - found
[cmake] -- Looking for connect
[cmake] -- Looking for connect - found
[cmake] -- Looking for remove
[cmake] -- Looking for remove - found
[cmake] -- Looking for shmat
[cmake] -- Looking for shmat - found
[cmake] -- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
[cmake] -- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
[cmake] -- Build spdlog: 1.8.5
[cmake] -- Build type: Debug
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: /home/tirthankar/projects/physicc/Light/build
```

Edit: I [opened an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/2053) on the CMake Tools GitHub page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-H` option is used for printing the help documentation for CMake.

`-H` has never been a standard or documented CMake flag for generating a project. You should not use it and you should disregard any "resources" that encourage you to use undocumented flags. If a Visual Studio Code extension is using it, you should open an issue with the authors of the extension.

The documented equivalent is `-S`, which sets the source directory. By default, it is the current directory. It was introduced in CMake 3.13. See the latest documentation here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#generate-a-project-buildsystem

There might be subtle behavioral differences between `-H` and `-S`. Do not use undocumented/internal flags.

Comment: @linuxUser123 - I thought it was excessive and didn't add anything to the answer. If you have a narrower edit in mind that doesn't list everything CMake can do, I might approve it.

Answer (score 0):

`-H` is indeed the flag for displaying the help docs, as @[Alex Reinking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2137996/alex-reinking), but there is another undocumented meaning.

While looking for good resources for learning CMake, I stumbled across [CGold](https://cgold.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which [also mentions the `-H` flag as a way to supply the path to the source](https://cgold.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glossary/-H.html).

> Add `-H<path-to-source-tree>` to set directory with `CMakeLists.txt`. This internal option is not documented but [widely used by community](https://cgold.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glossary/-H.html). There must be no spaces between `-H` and `<path-to-source-tree>` (otherwise option will be interpreted as synonym to `--help`). Always must be used with `-B` option.

Here are [some](https://github.com/topfreegames/libpitaya-cluster/blob/99152fd062591a4f8abdf93d3022462fdb47e9a0/cpp-lib/Makefile#L36) [specific](https://github.com/MoDeNa-EUProject/MoDeNa/blob/ba08ebbfed25bec742316dcd665c0b9941658232/applications/PUfoam/foamExpansion/build#L7) [pointers](https://github.com/NLESC-JCER/EigenCuda/blob/be5935f9c0010f666d925e426f013480d3c876cc/README.md?plain=1#L12) to projects which use (or recommend using) the `-H` flag to point to the source directory.

In fact, as CGold suggests, there was a patch submitted a long time ago which aimed to [actually document the internal `-H` flag](https://www.mail-archive.com/cmake-developers@cmake.org/msg16693.html).

However, it should be noted that one of the developers replied with

> These are undocumented because they are internal options that
> are not meant for public use.

So, we should *not* use those flags, and stick to the functionally equivalent (as pointed out by @Alex Reinking) `-S` flag if we need to pass in the source directory.